# using Node modules with Flow

Tags: node.js, flowtype

Flow has builtin support for standard Node modules such as "fs".
What is the proper way to use those?
I tried this:

```
const fs: fs = require('fs');
fs.someUnknownMethod();
```

I expected Flow to flag that last line, but it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the type annotation:

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.someUnknownMethod();
```

There is no type `fs` defined, and so when you use `fs` as a type it looks like Flow is referring to the variable itself somehow. Pretty weird and that should probably be an error, but at least you can just remove the annotation and Flow will give you the errors you expect.